# Getting value from input field vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get the value of my input field with vanilla javascript to create a tip calculator.

For some reason, the value returns but as empty. I have tried innerText, innetHTML, value, and it doesn't work.

Can someone point me what is my mistake here?

```js
const calculateTipBtn = document.getElementById('calculate');
const totalBill = document.getElementById('totalBill').value;
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');

calculateTipBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (totalBill.value === '') {
    console.log('Value can\'t be empty')
  } else {
    alert('there is something')
    console.log(totalBill)
  }
  console.log(totalBill)
})

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.reload()
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>Vanilla Tip Calculator</header>

  <div class="content">
    <label for="totalBill">Enter Total bill</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="totalBill">
    <label for="tipPercentage"> How much tip are you feeling?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="15"><span>15%</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="20"><span>20%</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="30"><span>30%</span>
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tip-result"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to push below line inside the `addEventListener`. You are caputuring or taking value at the start of the script, till then the input is empty and then the value will be `empty`. So I think you want to take a value when you enter something in the input and when you click `calculate` button. i.e. inside the event listener.

```
calculateTipBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const totalBill = document.getElementById('totalBill').value; // THIS
  if (totalBill.value === '') {
    console.log("Value can't be empty");
  } else {
    alert('there is something');
    console.log(totalBill);
  }
  console.log(totalBill);
});
```

```js
const calculateTipBtn = document.getElementById('calculate');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
const totalBill = document.getElementById('totalBill');

calculateTipBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const totalBillValue = totalBill.value;
  if (totalBill.value === '') {
    console.log("Value can't be empty");
  } else {
    alert('there is something');
    console.log(totalBillValue);
  }
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>Vanilla Tip Calculator</header>

  <div class="content">
    <label for="totalBill">Enter Total bill</label>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="totalBill" />
    <label for="tipPercentage"> How much tip are you feeling?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="15" /><span>15%</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="20" /><span>20%</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" value="30" /><span>30%</span>
    <br />
    <button id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tip-result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, even after moving my if condition will show that there is something whenever the value is empty, why is that?

Comment: Also why would the const outside the function does not work, it should be accessible, I'm confused.

Comment: I added `if (!totalBill.value)` instead and now it should value cant be empty, thank you

Comment: The first block of code is confusing as it sets totalBill equal to value and then uses totalBill.value.  That is corrected in the second block.

Comment: @Yogi I've shown both ways. More the merrier

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to move

```
const totalBill = document.getElementById('totalBill').value;
```

Inside the on click event, otherwise you will read the empty value when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `totalBill` variable on script load and before you click on the `calculate` button. move `totalBill` inside onClick

```
const calculateTipBtn = document.getElementById('calculate');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');

calculateTipBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const totalBill = document.getElementById('totalBill').value;
  if (totalBill === '') {
    console.log('Value can\'t be empty')
  } else {
    alert('there is something')
    console.log(totalBill)
  }
})

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.reload()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads you're already assigning the value from the input into the variable but at that point it's an empty string which is why you're getting that output. So you need to get that value when the calculate button is clicked instead.

In this example I've moved your markup around a little (changed the check boxes to radio buttons since you shouldn't be able to add multiple tip values), and added a new function that enables/disables the calculate button if nothing has been entered into the total bill input. It then calculates and outputs both the tip, and the total (plus tip).

```js
const totalBill = document.querySelector('#totalBill');
const calculate = document.querySelector('.calculate');
const tipResult = document.querySelector('.tipResult');
const totalResult = document.querySelector('.totalResult');

totalBill.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
calculate.addEventListener('click', handleCalculate);

function handleInput() {
  if (this.value && !Number.isNaN(+this.value)) {
    calculate.disabled = false;
  } else {
    calculate.disabled = true;
  }
}

function handleCalculate() {
  const total = +totalBill.value;
  const tipSelector = '[name="tip"]:checked';
  const tip = +document.querySelector(tipSelector).value;
  const calc = (total * tip) / 100;
  tipResult.textContent = calc;
  totalResult.textContent = total + tip;
}
```

```css
.totalBill, .tip, .tipWrapper { display: block; margin: 0.5em 0; }
.calculate { background: lightgreen; border-radius: 5px; }
.calculate:disabled { background: lightsalmon; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <label class="totalBill" for="totalBill">
    Enter bill total
    <input type="text" name="total" id="totalBill">
  </label>
  <label class="tip">
    How much tip are you adding?
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="15" checked>15%</input>
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="20">20</input>
    <input type="radio" name="tip" value="30">30%</input>
  </label>
  <button class="calculate" disabled>Calculate!</button>
</div>
<div class="tipWrapper">
  Tip: <span class="tipResult"></span>
</div>
<div class="totalWrapper">
  Total: <span class="totalResult"></span>
</div>
```